# Is it possible to add a license check (using License Verification Library) to a Service?

Tags: android, service, android-lvl

The fourth task in integrating the LVL with one's application code, as is described by http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html, is "Adding code to check the license in one's application's main Activity". The document says:

> Once you've implemented a Policy for
>   managing access to your application,
>   the next step is to add a license
>   check to your application, which
>   initiates a query to the licensing
>   server if needed and manages access to
>   the application based on the license
>   response. All of the work of adding
>   the license check and handling the
>   response takes place in your main
>   Activity source file.

What happens if the application has no Activity class? In an application consisting only of an Android Service, can we add license check code to a Service source file instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting the service from an activity, you can implement the LVL in the startup activity. Alternatively, create an activity at startup ... something similar to startup splashscreen.